# When is it appropriate to edit vs. comment?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Please consider the following case:

I recently edited an answer that was *technically* incorrect (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22212186), but not in a way that would cause someone's code to stop working as expected.  The answer bothered me simply because it conflicted with the docs. A simple `man fwrite` showed me that.

My edit *barely* scraped by, with half of the reviewers rejecting it, but ultimately it was accepted. Those who rejected it felt that I should have commented rather than made an edit, and said my edit made no sense.

I found some basic information on the privileges page for editing (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).  It said, in part, the following:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged

Personally, I didn't consider my edit to be trivial since it was conflicting with the docs. Further, I felt that it was more appropriate as an edit because the post was approx. 8 years old and I want anyone who visits that page to be presented with correct information.

When is it appropriate to comment, and when is it appropriate to edit? Should we comment in lieu of editing?

Comment: So my edit was appropriate because it corrected a syntax error? (P.S. apologies for the duplicate, I *did* do several searches before posting, but never saw that page come up.)

Comment: Fixing a simple misplaced argument like this is a good edit; also, good edit comment. The problem is that reviewers don't necessarily have the expertise to know if it's correct. So they err on the conservative side.

Comment: On another note, it would be nice to see this extra information from @Makoto's linked page incorporated into the information on the privileges page for editing (or at least linked). A lot of great information on that post.